# Adding a dropdown menu to my navigation bar moved that child to the right

Tags: html, css

When I tried to add a dropdown menu to my navigation bar it sent that child to the right of the navigation bar. I want it to be the 3rd child. How can I fix that? I tried to make it an absolute to keep its place however, it will then place itself over another child. I do not want that.

```css
rightNav {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    background: white;
    
}

.rightNav:hover{
    color: #0067ff;
    transition-duration: .4s;
}

.bar {
    background-color: white;
}

.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;  
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    transition: .1s;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div>
    <a href="#home" class="logo">LOGO</a>
    <div class="w3-right smallScreen">
        <a href="index.html" class="rightNav">HOME</a>
        <a href="director.html#slider-image-1" class="rightNav">DIRECTOR OF BANDS</a>
        <div  class="dropdown">
        <a href="#contact" class="rightNav dropdown dropbtn">MARCHING BAND</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">MARCHING BAND</a>
              <a href="#">STAFF</a>
              <a href="#">MUSIC</a>
              </div>
            </div>
        <a href="#contact" class="rightNav">CONCERT BAND</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="rightNav">JAZZ BAND</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="rightNav">CLASSES</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="rightNav">MEDIA</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="rightNav">CONTACT US</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Antonio.

I tried replicating your code to troubleshoot it, but the CSS is poorly pasted, so I won't be able to give you a full picture on it right now.

If I understand correctly, the issue you're facing is that the drop-down content isn't behaving as such, instead just showing up as links in the nav-bar. Correct?

If that is the case, I would refer you to https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp as you'd need some JavaScript to make it work. There is some neat code there ready for the use. Also, I would strongly recommend that you use no spaces in any of the class names in your HTML, as it becomes quite impossible to reference them later in your CSS code.